# CORS Issue: No 'Access-Control-Allow-Origin' Header Present

Tags: c#, typescript, http

I'm encountering a CORS issue while trying to make a request from my Angular application to an ASP.NET Core backend. The error message is as follows:
Access to XMLHttpRequest at 'https://localhost:7289/cv/generate' from origin 'http://localhost:4200' has been blocked by CORS policy: Response to preflight request doesn't pass access control check: No 'Access-Control-Allow-Origin' header is present on the requested resource.
Details:

Problem Description:

I have an Angular app hosted on 'http://localhost:4200'.
The backend is an ASP.NET Core application with an endpoint at 'https://localhost:7289/cv/generate'.
When attempting to make a request from the Angular app to the backend, the CORS issue is encountered.

Error Details:
The error occurs on a preflight request, and the response lacks the 'Access-Control-Allow-Origin' header.

Attempts to Resolve:
I've checked the backend CORS settings, but the issue persists.
I've ensured that the necessary HTTP methods are allowed.
Additional Information:

I'm also facing a similar CORS issue with another endpoint: 'https://localhost:7289/personalinfo'.

ASP.NET Core CORS configuration:

```
services.AddCors(options =>
{
    options.AddPolicy("AllowAngularDev",
        builder =>
        {
            builder
                .WithOrigins("http://localhost:4200")
                .AllowAnyHeader()
                .AllowAnyMethod();
        });
});

// Use CORS
app.UseCors("AllowAngularDev");
```

Angular Service (personal-info.service.ts:

```
// personal-info.service.ts
import { Injectable } from '@angular/core';
import { HttpClient } from '@angular/common/http';
import { Observable } from 'rxjs';
import { PersonalInfo } from './personal-info.model';
import { environment } from 'src/environment/environment';

@Injectable({
  providedIn: 'root',
})
export class PersonalInfoService {
  private apiUrl = environment.apiUrl;

  constructor(private http: HttpClient) {}

  getPersonalInfo(): Observable<PersonalInfo> {
    return this.http.get<PersonalInfo>(`${this.apiUrl}/personalinfo`);
  }

  createPersonalInfo(personalInfo: PersonalInfo): Observable<PersonalInfo> {
    return this.http.post<PersonalInfo>(`${this.apiUrl}/personalinfo`, personalInfo);
  }

  updatePersonalInfo(personalInfo: PersonalInfo): Observable<PersonalInfo> {
    const url = `${this.apiUrl}/personalinfo/${personalInfo.userId}`;
    return this.http.put<PersonalInfo>(url, personalInfo);
  }

  deletePersonalInfo(userId: number): Observable<void> {
    const url = `${this.apiUrl}/personalinfo/${userId}`;
    return this.http.delete<void>(url);
  }
}
```

ASP.NET Core Controller (CVController.cs):

```
using Microsoft.AspNetCore.Mvc;
using ResumeBuilder.Models;
using ResumeBuilder.Services;
using System;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using Microsoft.AspNetCore.Cors; // Add this line for enabling CORS

namespace ResumeBuilder.Controllers
{
    [Route("api/[controller]")]
    [ApiController]
    [EnableCors("AllowAll")] // Add this line to enable CORS
    public class CvController : ControllerBase
    {
        private readonly CvService _cvService;
        private readonly PdfService _pdfService;

        public CvController(CvService cvService, PdfService pdfService)
        {
            _cvService = cvService;
            _pdfService = pdfService;
        }

        [HttpGet]
        public IActionResult Get()
        {
            try
            {
                List<CV> cvs = _cvService.GetAllCvs();
                return Ok(cvs);
            }
            catch (Exception ex)
            {
                Console.WriteLine(ex.Message);
                return StatusCode(500, "An error occurred while fetching CVs.");
            }
        }

        [HttpPost]
        public IActionResult Post([FromBody] CV cv)
        {
            try
            {
                // Extract individual components from the CV object
                Personalinfo personalInfo = cv.PersonalInfo;
                List<Education> educationList = cv.EducationList;
                List<WorkEx> workExperienceList = cv.WorkExperienceList;
                Skills skills = cv.CVSkills;

                // Call the SaveCv method with the extracted parameters
                _cvService.SaveCv(personalInfo, educationList, workExperienceList, skills);

                return Created("CV saved successfully", "CV saved successfully");
            }
            catch (Exception ex)
            {
                Console.WriteLine(ex.Message);
                return StatusCode(500, "An error occurred while saving the CV.");
            }
        }

        [HttpGet("download/{cvId}")]
        public IActionResult DownloadPdf(int cvId)
        {
            try
            {
                CV cv = _cvService.GetCvById(cvId);
                if (cv == null)
                {
                    return NotFound("CV not found");
                }

                // Generate a unique file name, e.g., based on CV's full name and current timestamp
                string fileName = $"{cv.PersonalInfo.FullName}_Resume_{DateTime.Now:yyyyMMddHHmmss}.pdf";
                string filePath = Path.Combine("wwwroot", "pdfs", fileName);

                // Generate the PDF and save it to the specified file path
                _pdfService.GeneratePdf(cv, filePath);

                // Return the file for download
                return PhysicalFile(filePath, "application/pdf", fileName);
            }
            catch (Exception ex)
            {
                Console.WriteLine(ex.Message);
                return StatusCode(500, "An error occurred while generating the PDF.");
            }
        }
    }
}
```

How can I resolve this CORS issue and ensure that the 'Access-Control-Allow-Origin' header is present in the response?

I attempted to resolve the CORS issue by:

1.Checking the CORS configuration in my ASP.NET Core backend.

2.Ensuring that the necessary HTTP methods are allowed.

3.Verifying the Angular HTTP request headers.

4.Reviewing relevant documentation for CORS configuration in both Angular and ASP.NET Core.

I expected that these steps would resolve the issue and that I could make successful requests from my Angular app to the ASP.NET Core backend. However, despite these efforts, the CORS issue persists, and the error message mentioned in the question still occurs

Comment: Remove the EnableCors tag from the controller since you're using a policy in startup.

Comment: Alright thank you i will implement the change you suggested

Answer (score 2):

1. Do what @GH DevOps said in comment
2. When do You call UseCors? Do You call any 'use...' middleware before UseCors?
   Try to make it first middleware
3. Maybe try to remove 'addpolicy' and configure directly like above:

```
var app = builder.Build();
// This must be first line after 'builder.build()' - no other middleware
app.UseCors(c => c.WithOrigins(new string[] { "http://localhost:4200" })
    .AllowAnyMethod()
    .AllowCredentials()
    .AllowAnyHeader())
```

Comment: Alright thank you i will implement the changes you suggested